# diaspora: how to apply admin role?

Tags: postgresql, diaspora

I have a pod running based on https://hub.docker.com/r/koehn/diaspora/

I found a FAQ entry about the Admin Role https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/FAQ_for_pod_maintainers#What_are_roles_and_how_do_I_use_them.3F_.2F_Make_yourself_an_admin_or_assign_moderators

Unfortunately, the "rails console" does not work in that container (1).

Could I add the admin role directly in the database? I found my intitial user in the "users" table and see a "roles" table that is currently empty. Just unsure what I would have to INSERT there

(1) on first try I got a *bundle not found*. I figured that I had to install that missing gem. But even with that done I don't get the mentioned command to run:

```
diaspora@e4447573f534:~$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like](https://gitlab.koehn.com/docker/diaspora/blob/master/run_as_diaspora.sh#L19) diaspora* is installed to `/home/diaspora/diaspora` within the image. You need to run the command in the FAQ from within that folder, so `cd` to it first.